# Microsoft Azure VPN WebApp not communicating with external SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service

The problem I have is that we're trying to use our WebApp in Microsoft Azure to connect to an external SQL-database (not our own) through a VPN. The SQL-database is only allowing connections from our local IP-addresses that we put up as a Network (for example 176.0.0.0/24).
We are now connected to the same virtual private network, and through our Azure-VM we can now connect to the SQL-Server through SQL Server Management Studio.

Now we want to do the same with a WebApp, but we're not getting through to the server. It gets "Not authenticated" before reaching the SQL-Server (probably the server isn't accepting our IP from the WebApp).

The different problems I have tried to look through is:

- Do we only try to connect through our Outbound IPs?
- Is the WebApp not connected to the VPN?

I have unfortunatley not found any real answers, and neither any solutions to my problem. If you have any ideas of how to solve our problem, or maybe know how I could tunnel all of the SQL-calls through the VM, the help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using V1 or V2 resources?

Comment: Good question, since we're trying to migrate, I would say some things are in V1 and some are in V2. The VM and Virtual Netowrk is V1 (Classic), but I'm not sure wether the rest are V1 or V2.. How can I see if the WebApps are V1 or V2?

Answer (score 1):

Hybrid connection is one option. What you can also do is enable point-to-site in your VPN. Once you do that, you can directly integrate your web app to the vnet and your connections will work. (Go to your web app -> Settings -> Networking -> VNet Integration)

If your Vnet is V1(older way of creating VNs) then enabling point to site is very straightforward. You can do it through portal. For V2 Vnets you have to do it through powershell commands.
Here is a link for the documentation which explains both the options.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/

Comment: This might be the solution, but the VPN we are connecting to might have problems with their Point-to-Site configuration, and that might be the problem. Just a heads up if others are coming to the same problems; I think you're able to configure Point-to-site in Azure Portal for V2 if you try to do it through: AppServices -> Settings -> Networking -> VNet -> Create a new Virtual Network. 
You can't modify the Point-to-site without powershell though.

Comment: Yes you are right. If you already have a V2 Vnet created then the only way to enable point to site is via PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to "tunnel all of the SQL-calls through the VM". You may want to use hybrid connections (cf https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-overview/).

The principle is to have an agent installed on the VM that can access the database with the correct IP address.

Suppose you can access the SQL DB as mysqldbsrv from the VM. You add an hybrid connection associated to your web app, you install the agent on the VM. Then, when you connect to mysqldbsrv from the Web App, you go through the VM.